# No sound from Java application - but sound is working from other apps

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a java app for Linux arm-32 (to be run on a Raspberry pi). I develop with OpenJDK and compile the program into a .jar-file with all dependencies included.  The app will play mp3-files and it works fine on my win10 development machine running the same .jar-file as I run on the raspberry pi.

Mp3-files also play nicely on the raspberry using the VLC-player, so there should not be any issues playing mp3 at the raspberry itself, no missing decoder for mp3.

When I run it on the raspberry pi, no sound is omitted and no exceptions are thrown. I can also see the progress of the mp3 playing as the code writes to the console every percentage the file is processed.

I tried using a number of different version of JDKs (AdoptOpenJDK 11, Oracle OpenJDK 11, Bellsoft OpenJDK 13) but no difference.

Are there any specific configuration that needs to be done to play sound from java? I even tried to play a simple beep sound, works in win10 but not at the raspberry.

java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

Any ideas what to check next!?

Comment: Update:

Tried different versions of Raspbian/Raspberry pi os including the new 64 bit version, in combination with different version of OpenJDK ranging from Java8 to Java13. No success

This weekend I tried the Ubuntu Server for ARM64 instead, installed it together with the Ubuntu minimal desktop. Installed Bellsoft OpenJDK15 (the all-new Java15 version) for ARM64. 

BANG!! Sound works :-) Issue solved